# How to get data from axios reponse outside the call function

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

I'm trying to get a video title from a axios GET to a video API:

```
// METHOD GETTING A VIDEO ID:

latestVideo(videoID) {

  var self = this;
  var title;

  axios.get('http://video-api.dev/'+videoID)
  .then(response => {
    this.title = response.data.title
    console.log(response.data.title) //returns the correct title
  })
  return title // returns nothing

}
```

Console log shows the title, but I need to pass this to outside the call function, to have it available in my Vue app.

I've tried declaring `var self=this` but it does not seem to have any effect. Have I missed something?

Comment: `this.title` != `title` you initialized an empty `var title` and return it empty

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 0):

Well, returns nothing because you are not assigning any value to the variable, you will have to assign the response data to a variable when the request fulfill:

```
latestVideo(videoID) {

  // var self = this;
  // var title;

  axios.get('http://video-api.dev/'+videoID)
  .then(response => {
    this.title = response.data.title
    console.log(response.data.title) //returns the correct title
  })
  // return title // not needed

}
```

Then, when the promise (the request) is resolved you can access to the variable from the component (`this.title`)

You don't have to use the self switch if you are using arrow syntax.

Comment: `response` is not defined when declaring the variable

Comment: @FilipBlaauw in this case `title` would be always undefined since you are dealing with async data.You should return the `title` in the callback of `then`.

Comment: True, I will change the answer

Answer (score 0):

You're returning title, when assigning the response to `this.title`, try returning `this.title`.
I am making an assumption that `latestVideo` lives inside a class

```
class x {

latestVideo(videoID) {
    axios.get('http://video-api.dev/'+videoID)
    .then(response => {
        this.title = response.data.title
        console.log(response.data.title) //returns the correct title
    });

    return this.title
}}
```